# Using 32bit pintool on a 64 bit machine

Tags: 32bit-64bit, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am new to pintool and I spent weeks on this problem:

I have a 64 bit architecture running ubuntu 14.04 and I try to use a pintool (source/tools/SimpleExample - trace.cpp) on a 32 bit binary. I used the following command:

make obj-ia32/trace.so TARGET=ia32

to create the obj-ia32 folder including the (hopefully) compiled 32-bit version of trace.cpp. I think this worked, however when I then try to use

../../../pin -t obj-ia32/trace.so -- /path/to/binary/binary.o

I receive the following error:

E: Unable to load obj-ia32/trace.so.  Check the architecture type.

Do you have any idea how I can manage to use pintool on a 64bit machine on 32bit binaries? I know I need to compile the specific tool to 32 (which I thought I did above). I looked through the entire user manual multiple times, but I just can't seem to find the solution. Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions or hints you can give me.

Cheers!